# Dataset from Cells AND Matrices - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dataset, cells

I am trying ti display a several data elements I have. Some are strings and some are numeric. I would like to display them through the dataset function.

The strings are in cells, and the numeric data is in arrays.

I have constructed a cell of cells and arrays in the following manner:

`dataCell = {stringData, numericData};`

Then I converted this to a data set in the following manner:

`dataSet = cell2dataset(dataCell, 'VarNames', headers);`

The problem is with the output:

```
dataSet = 

stringData            numericData                   
{9x1 cell}            [9x1 double]
```

I was wondering, how is it possible to have the content of these cells and arrays displayed instead of their sizes?

Edit: The following will not work:

`dataSet({[stringData, numericData], headers{:}}, 'obsnames', rowObs);`

Answer (score 1):

Actually silly from me. Dataset does it by default but using the following syntax:

`ds = dataset(numericData, stringData);`